# Insert Row in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, insert, row

I am trying to create a loop in Excel to insert an entire row when there is a value change in column A. It goes through the loop once and works perfectly. It inserts the row like it is suppose to but when it loops and the value changes again it jumps straight to end sub rather than inserting a new row. I have tried to do this multiple ways.

Below is the simple loop I made to see if it works. This code works from the bottom up.

```
Do Until ActiveCell = ""

    If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
End If
Loop
```

Comment: A row in what?  Is this Excel?  If so, you should tag it appropriately.

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: What is the context  of this code, what triggers it? Please provide a few rows of sample data, before and what it should be after this code, and also what the result actually is.

Comment: Brandon, do you understand why I asked you what context your code is running in? For example, what is the `Sub` name? What is it that triggers the code to run (if it is not an event, which could be determined by the `Sub` name)? An event like f.ex. `Worksheet_Change`, or something else? Do you understand why I asked you for some sample data (in column A, as others are not significant), just some 4 or 5 cells of whatever text or numbers. How that data looked like before your code run, what it looked like after your code run, and what you expected it to look like (in case it was different)

Comment: You have received, by now, three answers. All signalling uncertainty of what you are asking. They all include phrases like *...assuming you are using...*, *I'm assuming...* or *...It reads to me like you are attempting...*. None of these answers give you a firm answer to your problem, because you have not explained the details around your problem. Yet I know the problem is easily solvable, if you just would be clear in your problem description. The idea with Stack Overflow is to ask detailed questions, and get spot on answers. Both questions and answers being usefull also for future readers.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will post another question with more detail. I'm really new at all of this and don't always know how to ask my questions. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It reads to me like you are attempting to circumvent the `Change` event. I suggest reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/worksheet-object-events) particularly the `Worksheet_Change`[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change). If you try and implement the `Change` event and are still having issues, I suggest you edit your original question to provide a bit more clarity and offer more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this loop is part of a larger piece of code.  If so, make sure that the code is returning to the bottom of the sheet (or whatever location is desired).  Since you are telling the loop to stop at an empty cell, running the code again without resetting the position of activecell will automatically find and empty cell and exit the loop.

As you said, the actual code for adding the blank rows itself works well, so it makes sense to look at the code around it.

Comment: It works until it hit the "ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert" the second time, then it jumps to end sub.

Answer (score 0):

@Bradon As I can see your code,it might be going into infinite loop [assuming you are using WorkSheet_Change event to catch any change in sheet]
Any change in worksheet trigger WorkSheet_Change event; in your case inserting row into worksheet is triggering the Worksheet_Change event

I will suggest you to post your entire code if possible
or
change you code like below [still assuming you are using WorkSheet_Change event]

add new sheet say "Config" and only once manually set A1 value to "True"

In worksheet change event use if condition

```
if Sheets("Config").Range("A1").Value = "True" then
call MyProcedure
end if
```

In Procedure

```
sub MyProcedure()
Sheets("Config").Range("A1").Value = "False"
your Do while loop here
Sheets("Config").Range("A1").Value = "True"
```